# PHPUnit Selenium - Can I use verify methods with a message?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

In PHPUnit, I want to use methods like `verifyText()` with an optional message as the last parameter, like I do with `assertStringEquals($expected, $actual, $message)`. It doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

I would tell myself to read the code, but I tried and I can't even figure out how *any* of the `verify()` methods get called. It must be some `__call()` function but I don't see it. So that's my follow-up question, how do the `verify()` methods get called? Then I could override them if I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm exploring the same question, albeit in the context of Selenium.

I found, grepping the source, an array $autoGeneratedCommands, which is set up in SeleniumTestCase/Driver. The mechanism here implements/maps verifyTextPresent() by a call to verifyCommand(), which calls assertCommand(). Subsequently one of the family assert*() is called... omitting the message in the call. This seems like an inadvertant feature to me. Well, coded bug.